# Not passing data through to blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to send some data through to a blade file but I'm not getting anything, it is just returning to the page
without displaying the message.

Here is my controller code

```
    public function missingProducts(Category $category)
    {
        $oldProducts = Product::where('category', $category->id)->get();
        $newProducts = Product::where('category', request('category'))->get();

        $oldArr = [];
        foreach($oldProducts as $oldProduct)
        {
            $oldArr[] = $oldProduct->name;
        }

        $newArr = [];
        foreach($newProducts as $newProduct)
        {
            $newArr[] = $newProduct->name;
        }

        $missingProducts = array_diff($oldArr, $newArr);

        if(!empty($missingProducts))
        {
            return redirect()->route('admin.category', ['category' => $category->id])
                                    ->with(['missingProducts' => $missingProducts]);
        }else{
            dd('there is NO products missing');
        }
    }
```

My blade file

```
    @if(!empty($missingProducts))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            We are missing products
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: the only things your controller can do are return a redirect or die, so there is no view involved here ... if you want to redirect to this other page then that data would be in the session, not part of the view data  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data  that will show you how flashed session data works and how to access it in the view

Comment: Also, data provided for blade view can (and should) be written as `return redirect()->route('admin.category', ['category' => $category->id, 'missingProducts' => $missingProducts])` or even better `return redirect()->route('admin.category', compact('category', 'missingProducts'));`.

Comment: @Tpojka it seems like it should be flashed session data not inputs of the request, at least the `missingProducts` part ... then again this method they have seems odd itself

Comment: @lagbox You are quite right. I actually meant on `view()` helper, didn't read best way the question. I will keep comment to leave your comment has more sense. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you returned your data with `->with(['missingProducts' => $missingProducts])` it's stored in flash session. This means the data will be available only once (on first redirect). In order to read that data, you can't use a variable, but you need to get it from session instead:

```
@if(!session()->has('missingProducts'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
      We are missing products
  </div>
@endif
```

You can read more about flashed session data on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the user to a route so either you need to append your data values in url to use them in blade or you have to set it in session first then redirect on the url and there you can access is via session if that's the required case, otherwise you need to return view and then pass the data you want.